# Is it possible to use word completion (e.g. `Ctrl-N`) in Ex mode?

Tags: autocompletion, ex-mode

I want to use word completion in Ex mode, similar to using `Ctrl-N` in Insert mode to complete the current word.

Suppose, I want to do a substitution: `:%s/<pattern>/<replacement>/gc`. If the cursor is on the word to substitute, I could use `C-R C-W` to paste it into Ex mode (command-line). However, sometimes the cursor is far away from the word to substitute, and here word completion would be beneficial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly what you want, but you can get insert-like completion in Command-line window, which is opened with `q:`. Just add `b` option to `complete` in your `.vimrc`, so vim will scan all opened buffers.

```
:set complete+=b
```

See:

```
:h cmdline-window
:h 'complete'
```

Comment: Thank you. `cmdline-window` is Ex mode too, right? It’s just a window, instead of a single cmdline.

Comment: How do I see the `:h` for the proper version of `complete`? If I do `:h complete`, then I get help for a function `complete({startcol}, {matches})`.

Comment: Surround complete with single quotes like in answer.

Comment: Yes, cmdline-window allows you switch modes and execute command on Enter key press. Also it shows commands history, so you can search easy with /